# Angular/bootstrap show specific form validation message

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to have a required email input on a form, and I'd like to augment the input's label to show validity with specific messages.  I tried the markup below (simplified, and a few variants).  The actual can be found at [this fiddle illustrating the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddledan/HB7LU/3580/).

```
<label for="email">Email
    <small class="help-inline" ng-show="form.email.$invalid-required"> (required)</small>
    <small class="help-inline" ng-show="form.email.$invalid-email"> (email)</small>
</label>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email"
        ng-model="model.email" required>
```

I'd like the 'required' message to appear when the input is empty, and when it's non-empty, I'd like the 'email' message to appear conditionally if angular email validation passes.

As you'll see in the fiddle, both messages appear and disappear together, even though, as I use the chrome inspector, the `$invalid` classes on the input seem to change appropriately.  This casts suspicion on the `ng-show` expression for the errors, but no matter what I try there I get the same behavior.

I've seen a couple answers ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897847/how-to-show-invalid-date-validation-message-for-angularstrap-datetimepicker)) that use a lot of code, but that answer seems a little roundabout.  I'm new to web, and already appalled by how bulky the html/code can get (each time I learn about a new streamlining idea, mine seems to double in size)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the expression for required to

`<label for="email">Email <small class="help-inline" ng-show="!form.email.$viewValue">`

and it would work.

The problem with Angular is that it does not allow invalid data in the model. So unless you provide a valid email value the linked model property remains empty and both the required and email validation fail.